# Setting up protected branches with github actions, gives me strange options

Tags: git, github-actions

I have setup a single github action to lint my node js code.

However when I go to protect my master branch with the github action theres is a ton in there, anyone know where these are coming from? Anyone else see strange results with protect branch actions?

Some are obvious like circleci but some are not??

Comment: Would be helpful if you could include a picture of the options that you are seeing.

Comment: Github just populates that list with any status checks it found in your repo. Ignore those and just use the ones that match either your configured ci or your workflow files.